# What is the proper way of referencing of Figures and Tables using RMarkdown on Kaggle?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kaggle

I've encountered an issue with referencing tables and figures using `\@ref(fig:figure1)` using RMarkdown. While this method works flawlessly in RStudio when rendering to PDF or HTML outputs, it does not appears to be working on Kaggle. For the reference, please look at my notebook, https://www.kaggle.com/code/sanjiv856/google-data-analytics-capstone-project-case-study, the referencing table and figures appears as `@ref(tab:table1)` or `@ref(fig:figure1)`. I would appreciate any advice or solutions.

I tried looking at others notebook, comments, and questions, but did not found anyone referencing tables and figures in this way.

I wish the figures and tables to be labelled in the text referring them as i.e., Table 1.1 or Figure 3.5, depending on where it appears on the text and/section as it appears on PDF or HTML rendered output.

Answer (score 0):

you can demonstrate it show figures and tables using chunk labels as one method to assigned labls in Rmarkdown kaggle:

````
---
title: "Example RMarkdown"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

### Figure Reference

```{r scatterplot, fig.cap="Scatter Plot Caption"}
# Example data
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
plot(x, y)

# Example data
mydata <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 28)
)
# Print table
knitr::kable(mydata, caption = "Example Table Caption")
````

1-Set up RMarkdown document with data.

- Then, I demonstrate how to reference a figure (`scatterplot`) and a table (`example_table`) using both chunk labels and manually assigned labels.
- The figures and tables are created using R code chunks, and the `fig.cap` and `caption` arguments are used to provide captions for them.
- In the last part, I reference these figures and tables in the text using `\@ref(label)` syntax.

you can adjust accordingly to your needs the above code. I hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, this method works for knitting to PDF or HTML, but this does not work on Kaggle, I did try with R code chunk names and captions, but this just leads to `@ref(tab:table1)` or `@ref(fig:figure1)`, but does not appear in proper format. If you have used this and it works, it will be very helpful if you can share the Kaggle notebook, for me have a look at?